# Code chunk identification algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, matlab, decode

I have a long string that consists of substrings. The task is to extract the substrings. A substring is defined by the following characteristics:

1. There is a finite set of characters (letters, numbers) that make up the string
2. Within a substring, a character can only repeat adjacent to itself
3. Substrings are of unknown length

The question is to define an algorithm that, given a string S, breaks it into substrings s that follow the above rules. The goal is to identify the minimum number such substrings (trivially, a single character would otherwise fit the bill).

An example of a string and its substrings:

```
AC3BDCAB223DADAC121BCD332221A
```

Which would have to be broken up like this:

```
AC3BD CAB223D AD AC12 1BCD33222 1A
      ^ C repeats
              ^ A repeats
                 ^ A repeats
                       ^ 1 repeats
                                ^ 1 repeats
```

Comment: It is unclear to me what the relationship is between "raw data" and the desired output. How do you know when a particular process has run, for example? What are the inputs / outputs of your processes?

Comment: @Floris Process is a sequence of alphabets A-E and numbers 1-3. Let us say P1= ED3AB. By my problem description, EDD33AB is also P1. My raw data is a sequence of subprocesses, I have to identify the chunks which make up a process. Hope this is clear.

Comment: Does it always start and end with the same two characters? And is the number of characters in a process always even?

Comment: yes, every process start and end with same two characters. The code length of each process is not always even. However, I would like to see, how even code lengths can be helpful.

Comment: What is the goal here - fewest processes? Fewest distinct processes? How do you know whether `ABAB` is one or two? There don't seem to be sufficient rules to come up with an algorithm.

Comment: The processes are indeed few. Final goal is to predict next process, given a sequence. ABAB  are two separate processes, as, in a process if there is an element with multiplicity more than 1, then the repeated element has to appear consecutively. A3CCCD is a valid process.. A3CCDC is not.

Comment: OK that makes it a LOT clearer. So as soon as a character shows up again we have a new process. That seems like an easy algorithm given limited number of symbols.

Comment: can you explain the algorithm to me?, both in mathematical way and plain English?

Comment: Make a list of all the characters you have encountered so far. When you come across one you already saw (and it is not repeated) you have found a process. Add it to the list of found processes, clear your "characters found" list and start again.

Comment: I have made one more edit which I believe reflects what you were asking. If that is the case, please delete the remainder of the question (or update my edit). I have written a short Python program that appears to produce the results you need, but I can't post it unless the question is re-opened - meaning it needs to be clear.

Comment: @Floris and generally note: I voted to reopen, then had second thoughts. I came back to look at the question again, and see that my vote was the last necessary to reopen this question. It still seems too broad, and there's no code in the question so it doesn't really seem like a programming problem, possibly off-topic as well. For future reference, you could have posted the code in a gist or pastebin (etc) and pasted the link here in the comments.

Comment: @ChrisBaker - thanks. I have posted my answer. I don't like using a "back door" (pastebin etc) to answer a closed question... I think that defeats the process.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, the following simple program does what you want:

```
inString = 'AC3BDCAB223DADAC121BCD332221A'

found = []
recent = inString[0]
found.append(recent)
breaks=[-1]
for i,c in enumerate(inString[1:]):
    if c == recent:
        continue
    if c in found:
        breaks.append(i)
        found = [c]
        recent = c
    else:
        found.append(c)
        recent = c

breaks.append(len(inString))

for ii in range(len(breaks)-1):
    print inString[breaks[ii]+1:breaks[ii+1]+1]
```

For the given input string, it produces as output:

```
AC3BD
CAB223D
AD
AC12
1BCD33222
1A
```

As you can see, `recent` is the last-seen character: this allows you to "keep going" if you have a repeated character. If you see a new character, you add it to the string of characters used so far in this chunk; and when you see a character again, you know it must belong to a new process.

If this is not what you needed, you have to clarify your question.